# Conan - Package method pack more than expected

Tags: c++, conan

I'm trying to use conan to create a package. All it's fine, but I do not really understand the way the method "package" is working:

I wrote the following "package" and package_info method:

```
def package(self):
  self.copy("*.so", dst="lib", keep_path=False)

def package_info(self):
  self.cpp_info.libs = [ "MyLib" ]
```

I ran:

```
conan install . --install-folder=.build/debug.x86 --profile=conan-debug.x86.txt
conan build . --build-folder=.build/debug.x86 --source-folder=.
conan package . --build-folder=.build/debug.x86 --source-folder=. --package-folder=.pack
```

But I notice that the package method alos pack header files.

```
conanfile.py (mylib/none) package: Packaged 57 '.h' files
```

But I do not want those header in my package.
Why are those header files also packaged while I do not write any code to copy "header"files in the package method ?
How to avoid those files to be packaged ?

Thank you very much

Here the conan-debug.x86.txt file:

```
[settings]
  arch=x86
  build_type=Debug
  compiler=gcc
  compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
  compiler.version=4.8
  os=Linux

[options]
  coverage=True
```

Comment: It seems like your are re-using something from your cache, because package command won't copy something which is not listed there, and there is no bug related to it because this feature is stable and no one reported in years. Also, you could use [create](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/create.html) command instead of the development flow.

Comment: This is a bit weird, if you can put a reproducible case in a zip folder or a repo, I would suggest to submit it to the issue tracker: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: Thank you @uilianries, yes, something from the cache was responsible (I was responsible to not clear the cache -))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @uilianries, yes, something from the cache was responsible (I was responsible to not clear the cache -))